# Python / Redis : Get Bitset string

Tags: python, redis

I'm wondering how i can get the string value of a bitset in redis, i have the following code :

```
import redis as redis


def main():
    redisClient = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
    redisClient.setbit("mybitset",5,1)
    bitset=redisClient.get("mybitset")
    print bitset # expect the output to be 100000


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly the `redisClient.get("mybitset")` call returns a string containing the binary data. Try replacing your `print bitset` with:

```
print "{0:b}".format(ord(bitset[0]))
```

This will only work if your bitset is one byte long. If it spans multiple bytes try using the [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module. For example, if it is two bytes long (i.e. a short):

```
print "{0:b}".format(struct.unpack(">h", bitset)[0])
```

Comment: Doesn't work : using the first print i get output as 100, using the second option print "{0:b}".format(struct.unpack(">h", bitset)[0]) I get error struct.error: unpack requires a string argument of length 2